# How I cant set Visible Again in Gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

My `Imageview` is in Grid Layout I have a ontouchlisteners when I Touch the imageview I set it in Invisible and I have a DragListener when I Drop the Imageview the

> Error(ConcurrentModificationException)

is appears I want to do is when I drop the Imageview the `Imageview` I Touch is set to Visible again.

How  can I make this work ?

this is my codes

```
   @Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int dragEvent = event.getAction();
    final View views = (View)event.getLocalState();
    switch (dragEvent) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;

  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;

   case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            views.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            views.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myshadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, myshadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please show the code you're using and the exact stacktrace that you're getting.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code as part of the question.

Comment: Sir can you help me in this codes ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Note this is a more specific form of code than *"your code"* or *"the code"*.